# Can jQuery do a POST of a ViewModel to a Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, viewmodel

I have my Html Textboxes created so that they will be bound to a custom view model when posting back to the server.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("CustomerFormViewModel.Email")%>
```

This works great if it's a traditional POST. I can then receive it on the Controller side with something like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomersFormViewModel model)
{
     //validate data, save customer, handle validation errors...
}
```

I want to know -- is it possible to do the POST via jQuery and still get the same behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible, there is no difference between a "traditional POST" and "AJAX Post". For example:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: '<%= Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customer") %>',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Eugene, I want to post a viewmodel to an action method, call one JavaScript method on success, and stay on the same page. Is using this the best practice?

Comment: perfect...i was wondering how to post the viewmodel to the controller and I have used the JSON.stringfy(), but the controller fails to accept the data. But the .serialize() has worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right, I think it's pretty simple

```
var formData = $("#form").serialize();

$.post("path/to/action", formData, function(data) { //success } );
```