# Pass ViewModel with jQuery post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I'm trying to do a post with jQuery in an MVC application, according to this SO answer here:
[Can jQuery do a POST of a ViewModel to a Controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160669/can-jquery-do-a-post-of-a-viewmodel-to-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

The difference is I am using it to delete an item in a dynamic view (never mind the fact that I'm posting a delete directly, this is a closed site by authorization, and I will use jQuery to confirm, I just don't want the user to have to go to a new page). And I therefore need to be able to send both the id and the ViewModel (the ViewModel to save any added items before deleting any). I'm not particularly happy with the solution by and large, but at this point I just need to get it to work!

So I tried to figure out how to send both the id and the ViewModel according to the SO post above, but I can't figure out how to get the ViewModel in with the named parameters. This doesn't work:

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: deleteurl,
        data: ({id : $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text(),vm: $('form').serialize()}),
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#rows").html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here's the POST action method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, LanguageViewModel vm)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vm.Languages.Count; i++)
            {
                var language = _repository.GetLanguage(vm.Languages[i].Id); //This is the key, get the original program object to update
                UpdateModel(language, "Languages[" + i + "]");
            }
            _repository.Save();
//Delete code will go here
         return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Languages", new { id = id });
        //return View();
        }
```

Again, it doesn't work, it doesn't even get to the action method in the debugger. If I remove the int id parameter from the action method it actually gets there, but with vm = null. I have no clue what to do, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Sorry, the return value should be as changed now, not return View().

UPDATE:

With a little help from Darin it's almost working:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(LanguageViewModel vm, FormCollection collection)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vm.Languages.Count; i++)
        {
            var language = _repository.GetLanguage(vm.Languages[i].Id); //This is the key, get the original program object to update
            UpdateModel(language, "Languages[" + i + "]");
        }
        _repository.Save(); 
        int id = Int32.Parse(collection["HiddenId"]);
        Language languageToDelete = _repository.GetLanguage(id);
        _repository.Delete(languageToDelete);
        vm.Languages.Remove(vm.Languages.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Id == id));
        _repository.Save();
        return PartialView("LanguageList", vm);
    }
```

But I have changed to return a PartialView (which was what I was supposed to do from the beginning since that is what the jQuery does - load a div with the results). But the problem is, after returning this Partial View from the action method and loading it in the div with jQuery, the $(".delete").click jQuery function doesn't work anymore...

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try including a hidden field inside your form that will hold the id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="hiddenid" value="" />
```

and then:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    $('#hiddenid').val(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: deleteurl,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#rows').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

which could be simplified to:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    $('#hiddenid').val(id);
    $('#rows').load(deleteurl, $('form').serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how will I get to both the id and the ViewModel in the action method then? What should the parameters in the action method be in your example to get to both of these?

Comment: @Anders Svensson, you don't need to modify your action method signature. Using this code you should get both the id and the view model bound in the action. Just make sure that there is no property called id on your view model or you might get strange results.

Comment: Ok, I tried exactly as you said, but it still doesn't even reach the action method, and by only sending the form as parameter, wouldn't the signature be wrong in this case? And I still don't understand how the method will have access to the id just because I put it in the hiddenid input?

Comment: @Anders Svensson, because you put it in a hidden field it will be serialized along with the other form values when you do `$('form').serialize()` and included in the request. Also if you use the `.load()` version instead of `$.ajax()` look with FireBug whether it uses a GET or POST request because your action is marked with `[HttpPost]` and it accepts only POST requests. So if you send a GET request it won't be hit. There might be other reasons for the action not being hit such as javascript errors, ... So analyze with FireBug.

Comment: I actually got it working with your help, but had to change a bit, see above. I'm not saying I like my code here, but I'm getting closer to something that works now. But there is one big problem left: the jQuery doesn't work on the id=add link after returning a partialview... Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the delete jQuery function is not working after returning the Partial View!

Comment: Found out myself that you need to use the jquery live function in cases like these, and then it worked. Thanks for your help with the main issue!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried appending the id to the deleteurl before posting?

Something like this has worked for me:

```
deleturl = deleteurl + "/" + id;
```

hth,

\ ^ / i l l

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I could give it a go, but I seem to remember that if you have a data parameter in the ajax method it overrides parameters in the url or something, I'm not sure. But I'll check!

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the FormCollection as the second argument instead of viewmodel. Then you can do a TryUpdateModel on your language object before saving and/or deleting.

Comment: I don't think that will help I'm afraid, I need the ViewModel passed in here. The dynamic aspect of the View (both editing, adding and deleting in the same View) requires a different updating code (I've tried to find simpler ways for weeks in this forum...)