# Passing jquery object to MVC action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I am trying to use `.ajax()` to post a `People` object to a MVC2 action that expects a ViewModel as parameter. The ViewModel has a `People` property.

The problem is that when the MVC action is activated, the `ajax()` postback `People` object is always null. I used Fiddler to diagnose the problem. The property values in the `People` object are all contained in the header. Here is my client jQuery script. Please note that I used three methods to stuff the property values into People object, but none of them works.

```
        StaffDlg.delegate("#SaveButton", "click",
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            People["PKey"] = $("#PKey").val();
            People["FName"] = $("#FName").val();
            People["LName"] = $("#LName").val();
            People["MName"] = $("#MName").val();
            People["SSN"] = $("#SSN").val();
            People["Gender"] = $("#Gender").val();
            People["DOB"] = $("#DOB").val();
            People["BirthPlace"] = $("#BirthPlace").val();
            People["NetworkAccount"] = $("#NetworkAccount").val();

            var pkey = $("#PKey").val();
            var action;

            if (!isNaN(parseFloat(pkey)) && isFinite(pkey)) {
                action = "Edit" + "/" + pkey;
            }
            else {
                action = "Create";
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: getRootUrl() + "/Staff/" + action,
                //data: { FName: $("#FName").val(), LName: $("#LName").val(), MName: $("#MName").val(),
                //  SSN: $("#SSN").val(), Gender: $("#Gender").val(), DOB: $("#DOB").val(),
                //  BirthPlace: $("#BirthPlace").val(), NetworkAccount: $("#NetworkAccount").val()
                //},
                //data: JSON.stringify(People),
                data: $("Form").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#ajaxResponse").addClass("whiteOnGreen").html("Update succeeded");
                },
                error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#ajaxResponse").addClass("whiteOnRed").html("Failed to save the record!\r\n" +
                        textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + "\r\n" +
                        "data : " + JSON.stringify(People));
                }
            })
        } 
    );
```

and here is the MVC action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, StaffViewModel updatedStaff)
    {
        People staff = _staffService.GetStaff(id);

        if (updatedStaff == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TryUpdateModel<People>(staff, "staff"); 
            staff.RecordLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            staff.UpdatedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            _staffService.SaveStaff();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = thisStaff.PKey });

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return this.Json(staff, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(updatedStaff.previousURL))
                    return Redirect("/Staff/Startwith/" + staff.LName.Substring(1, 1));
                else
                    return Redirect(updatedStaff.previousURL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                string errorMessage = "<div class='whiteOnRed error'>"
                    + "The following errors occurred:<ul>";
                foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    var error = ModelState[key].Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += "<li>"
                            + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>";
                    }
                }
                errorMessage += "</ul></div>";
                return Json(new { Message = errorMessage });
            }
            else
                return View(updatedStaff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hiya, have you had a look into MVC ajax in .net - ajax call to the action - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the .ajax() not posting the form values to the MVC Create(People person) action.  It was the parameter type that this different than the one used in Edit(StaffViewModel).  Now both action accept the same type of parameter, StaffViewMode.

Answer (score 0):

You state that the form expects a StaffViewModel as a parameter, and a StaffViewModel has a People property... but you are not passing the full StafFViewModel object - instead you are passing a People object from the Ajax call, and hoping that the People property gets populated on the MVC end.

There is a disconnect there and the auto-binder doesn't know how to bridge it.

Try creating a controller method with a (int, People) signature, and see if that works for you.

Otherwise, you might need to create a custom binder.

Comment: According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160669/can-jquery-do-a-post-of-a-viewmodel-to-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc, it's no need to create either.  The MVC should be able to drill into the People property in the ViewModel and bind it's properties with the .ajax() posted People.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing dataType and contentType settings from your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: getRootUrl() + "/Staff/" + action,
    data: $("Form").serializeArray(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ajaxResponse").addClass("whiteOnGreen").html("Update succeeded");
    },
    error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#ajaxResponse").addClass("whiteOnRed").html("Failed to save the record!\r\n" +
            textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + "\r\n" +
            "data : " + JSON.stringify(People));
    }
})
```

Comment: I got the form data ajaxed to the MVC Edit(int id, StaffViewModel updatedStaff) action.  However, I still can't get the form data ajaxed to the Create(People person) action.  The .ajax() checks the $("#PKey").val() to determine which action to post. Do you know why it's not picked up by the Create action?  Does it matter that the Edit() accepts a ViewMode while the Create() accepts just the People entity? Thanks.